# Laravel Extending Blade Templates - error in $errors collection

Tags: php, laravel, templates, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 5.3. My first Laravel project/learning experience
In my blade file I use the following snippet to show the errors below a field after a PUT or POST request.

In this case the database field is called firstName

```
        @if ($errors->has('firstName'))
            <span class="help-block">
                <strong>{{ $errors->first('firstName') }}</strong>
            </span>
        @endif
```

Now since I have lot of fields, I have keep repeatings this block for every field. I looked up the Laravel docs on Blade templates (Extending Blade section) and thought I could do the following in the AppServiceProvider class (AppServiceProvider .php)

```
public function boot()
{
    //
    Blade::directive('showIfError', function($fieldName) {
        if ($errors->has('$fieldName')) {
            echo "<span class='help-block'>
            <strong> $errors->first('$fieldName') </strong>
            </span>";
        }
    });
}
```

and then use

@showIfError('firstName')

But no luck...I get the error 'Undefined variable: errors'

Looks like the Laravel error collection is not accessible in this view file.

Appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please include what you want to achieve ?

Comment: I do not want to copy and paste the if (errors...) block for each field in my form. Instead I want to a macro/blade template like @showIfError('fieldName') and the final output will be rendered like the span block given above.

Comment: I find that view caching is interfering with the output. If I delete all the files in storage (cache) folder I can get this to work using session('errors') but it works only once! Submitting the form again with the same errors does not produce any output! Because of this I am unable to fully test if any of the answers will work :-( 
In addition the Blade::directive function does not take 2 arguments.

Answer (score 3):

This is late reply, but hopefully it will help another person who comes along. A custom blade directive is supposed to return a string php code that will be evaluated when the template is rendered. Because the `$errors` variable is only available when the response is made, it won't work trying to evaluate it in the directive. The solution is this :

```
 // custom blade directive to render the error block if input has error
 // put this inside your service provider's boot method

     \Blade::directive('errorBlock', function ($input) {
            return
                '<?php if($errors->has('.$input.')):?>
                    <div class=\'form-control-feedback\'>
                        <i class=\'icon-cancel-circle2\'></i>
                    </div>
                    <span class=\'help-block\'>
                            <strong><?php echo $errors->first('.$input.') ?></strong>
                    </span>
                 <?php endif;?>';
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

The thing is `$errors` in not accessible in closure. Also, you can't pass whole object as directive closure accepts string only. With simple data you can `implode()` and then `explode()` it, but not with an object or a collection.

What you can do is to create `$errors` manually inside the closure.

I've tested it and it works as expected:

```
Blade::directive('showIfError', function($fieldName) {
    $errors = session('errors');

    if ($errors->has($fieldName)) {
        return "<span class='help-block'>".$errors->first($fieldName)."</span>";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the $errors variable is only available within the views. If you take a look at the Middleware that shares the variable (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/View/Middleware/ShareErrorsFromSession.php) you will see that it is stored in the session.

So you can access it as follows:

```
$errors = session()->get('errors');
```

Note in your example you do have a couple of other issues; the $fieldName variable should not be in quotes. Eg:

```
public function boot() {
Blade::directive('showIfError', function($fieldName) {
$errors = session()->get('errors');
 if ($errors->has($fieldName)) {
      echo "<span class='help-block'> <strong>". $errors->first($fieldName). "</strong> </span>";
 } 
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally wrote a PHP function inside my view and call it with various field names.
I hope this is a good approach. Not sure what is the best way to implement this.

```
function showIfError($fieldName)
{
    $errors=session('errors');
    if ( count( $errors)>0) {
        if (session('errors')->has($fieldName)) {
            $msg=$errors->first($fieldName);
            echo '<span class="help-block">
                    <strong>'. $msg.' </strong>
                </span>';
        }
    }

}
```